# Having a django model that can only contain a specified number of rows

Tags: django, django-models

I want to create a Django Group model whose members are in a Django Person Model...The Person instance can only occur in a specific number of groups...and a group can only accommodate a specific number of person instances

Answer (score 0):

Perform a check when trying to add a person to a group. Something like:

```
class Group(models.Model):
    def add_person(self, person):
        if person.groups.count() > max_groups_per_person:
            raise ValidationError("Can't add a person to more than %s groups" % max_groups_per_person)
        if self.people.count() = max_people_per_group:
            raise ValidationError("Can't add more than %s people to the group" % max_people_per_group)
```